# Can't get the nonce meaning using web3.py

Tags: web3.py, ganache

I'm following the freecodecamp solidity tutorial and unfortunately I get a mistake when I try to get the nonce meaning. I use web3.py and ganache as it's shown in the tutorial. Here's my code:

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
import json
from web3 import Web3

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

install_solc("0.6.0")
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)

# get bytecode
bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["evm"][
    "bytecode"
]["object"]

# get abi
abi = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["abi"]

# for connecting to ganache
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://0.0.0.0:8545"))
chain_id = 1337
my_address = "0xC674eC6962Ba5dEe7a1409187DE523663dbffB14"
private_key = "0x0e6322ac24bdac2508bc4b888486e98dd4a090d954b47fcbc9c1efc06970953"

# create the contract in python
SimpleStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
# get the latest transaction
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)
print(nonce)
```

It does create a contract at least when I print it gives me an answer. But when I try to create a nonce it gives the next mistake:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=8545): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001B91C7468E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10049]
```

Does anyone know where the problem can be?

Answer (score 2):

`http://0.0.0.0:8545` is not a valid Ethereum JSON-RPC node URL. PLease get a valid node.

[Here are some examples](https://ethereumnodes.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yeah, I changed it to http://127.0.0.1:8545 and it worked out

Answer (score 0):

Please double check the address from RPC Server on Ganache

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem but i am running web3 in WSL so anyone get error in WSL can go to ganache then settings then server then change host name to 127.22.32.1-vEthernert(WSL) then save and restart. so your problem solved

Comment: Please provide a relevant comment instead of an answer that does not address the question.